# What to do with odd span tags when using Pandoc to make markdown output

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have some Calibre created epubs that I want to make into markdown to use in Obsidian. I found Pandoc and my simple attempts at conversion are, among other things, losing the italics and passing the Calibre `span` tags through, which don't show as italics in Obsidian.

If I turn off the `raw_html` extension it doesn't pass all the `span` tags through, but I don't get any italics, either. What I want to do is convert the html:

```
<span class="italic">Some Words</span>
```

into italic text in my final markdown file. If Pandoc can do this, that would be great. Otherwise I'll take a swipe at converting the html before passing it into Pandoc, but a lot of the `span` tags that Calibre generated are stacked a few layers deep, so a really simple solution would be great.

Does Pandoc handle this directly or do I need to deal with the html first? I'm not just concerned with italics only, there are a bunch of other formatting issues that use variouos Calibre `span` tags that could be simpler, like bold and some headings. So I'm trying to work out a way to deal with them all.

**UPDATE:**

Since I had to do a lot of poking around the web and trial and error to get this working well enough for my needs, I thought it would be useful to post my first try at a lua filter. This has worked well on a few hundred html pages extracted (via unzip) from EPUBs seemingly authored by a tool called Calibre.

My ebooks are wordy references that are light on images, so my Image handler is simple enough for my needs. And I can grep the resulting files and fix any link issues. My set of Calibre EPUBs changed their internal structure depending on when they were created, so I keep adding new class names since there seemed to be no effort to maintain the same naming over time. Therefore I expect to modify this over time as I convert more of the files. I also expect markdown will be a better format going forward than EPUBs!

This is my first ever lua code so I expect it is a bit sloppy. Also, I used `--wrap=none` `-t commonmark` in a bash script that iterates a pandoc tranformation over all the files in my work directory.

```
-- Corrections for some Calibre oddities when using Pandoc to convert to markdown for Obsidian.
-- Note that I converting very old ebooks and that I don't know anything about Calibre.
function Span (span)
    -- Make italic for: <span class="italic">(“Hello there!”)</span>
    if span.classes:includes 'italic' then
        return pandoc.Emph(span.content)
    end

    -- Make bold for: <span class="bold">(“Hello there!”)</span>
    if span.classes:includes 'bold' then
        return pandoc.Strong(span.content)
    end

    -- Unclear what purpose these serve...
    if span.classes:includes 'calibre1' or span.classes:includes 'calibre2'
            or span.classes:includes 'calibre3' or span.classes:includes 'calibre4' then
        return pandoc.Strong(span.content)
    end

    -- My markdown reader (Obsidian) works with this when using commonmark output.
    if span.classes:includes 'underline' then
        span.attributes['style'] = 'text-decoration: double underline ;'
        return span
    end
end

function Image (img)
    -- Fix calibre6 images.
    if img.classes:includes 'calibre6' or img.classes:includes 'calibre9' then
        return pandoc.Image(img.caption, img.src, nil, nil)
    end
end

function Div (div)
    -- Put a horizontal line in for the page break, just to see where they are.
    if div.classes:includes 'mbp_pagebreak' then
        return '---'
    end
    -- These seem to be hardcoded page delimiters put in by calibre for ebook readers?
    if div.classes:includes 'calibre_4' or div.classes:includes 'calibre_13' then
        return '---'
    end
end
```

Finally, I should note that I wrote a script that renames all of the new markdown files by their first line. This put them in a coherent shape for adding to Obsidian, which uses the filesystem for organizing things. After a little editing and renaming I have a section of old reference books in my Obsidian vault that are easy to access on all my devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc does not parse CSS and hence has no way to know that this should be put into italics. A good solution is to modify pandoc's internal document representation using a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters).

```lua
function Span (span)
  if span.classes:includes 'italic' then
    return pandoc.Emph(span.content)
  end
end
```

This filter checks if the span has class `italic` and, if it does, converts it into *emphasized text*, which will usually be output in italics. Use the filter by saving it to a file and pass that file pandoc via the `--lua-filter` command line option.

You'll likely want to handle more classes; other pandoc constructors you might want to use are `pandoc.Strong` and `pandoc.Underline`, [etc.](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters#type-inline). Run pandoc with `--to=native` to see how pandoc represents the document internally.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the link and the explanation, I'm off to learn about Lua Filters and see if I can solve all of the problems that way. I'd glanced at the docs, but didn't have the context to understand how they might apply to my situation. And now I do, excellent!

Comment: After reading the docs to be sure I understood your explanation, I pasted your example into a file and added it to my command with the --lua-filter option and it worked exactly as needed. Thanks! I'm off to learn some lua so that I can tackle some more problems, interesting language. Incidentally, for future readers, I found this page useful: http://lua.space/general/extending-pandoc-with-lua

Comment: I've managed to solve most of the issues with the span tags, but this one has me stumped. The html contains: <span class="calibre1">SESSION 4</span> and when I print it out from the filter I get: Span ("",["calibre1"],[]) [Str "SESSION",Space,Str "4"] but I want to make it into a header, as if it were <h1>SESSION 4</h1> or, in markdown, just a # prefix to indicate a header. I can't figure out the right lua filter code, I guess it should be something like: pandoc.Header(1, span.content) but can't find docs or an example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, that's a harder one. Pandoc treats spans as *Inline* elements and headings as *Block* elements, and Inline elements can only be replaced by Inlines and Blocks through Blocks. Going from an Inline to a Block element is much harder. Can you open a new question about this? BTW, thanks for digging out my old blog post. Hearing that you found it useful made my day :)

Comment: OK, that is what I gathered by implication and it is good have it confirmed. I'm going to work on solving the inline issues first and then revisit the issue of headings. I have about a thousand or two pages to convert, so I have to think about how that works in Obsidian. This is a cosmetic issue that I'm going to leave for last and will open a new issue if needed. And your writings about filters that I've found on the web have been useful in trying to get a basic understanding of how to use Pandoc in real world problems, so thanks greatly!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Pandoc, but that is some bad HTML. And using better HTML may help you with your problem.

HTML should express the semantic meaning of the content, and

```
<span class="italic">Some Words</span>
```

doesn't express any semantic meaning, which is probably by Pandoc doesn't know what to do with it.

For one class names should express **why** something is formatted the way it is, not **how** it is formatted. For example, better class names could be `important` or `book-title` (because book titles are often formatted italic).

Furthermore the [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Element) (tag) `span` also doesn't express any meaning. But there is an element that (basically) means "important": [`<em>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em). So instead of `<span class="important">Some words</span>` it would be better to use `<em>Some Words</em>`.

Coming back to Pandoc: If the reason you are using italic, is because the text is important, then you should use `<em>` and because (EDIT) <s>is normally rendered as italic, then Pandoc may actually know to use italic, too.</s> (based on that other answer) Pandoc has the concept of emphasis (`pandoc.Empf`), so I'm quite sure it will be rendered either as italic or at least something else suitable.

There are more elements that are normally rendered as italic, so you could use those, too, if they are semantic correct for your usage, for example, [`<cite>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite) (which can used for book titles, as in my other example) or the more generic [`<i>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i).

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, and I agree totally, but I should have mentioned that I didn't create the html and wouldn't dream of doing it this way. Somebody used Calibre in the past to create the ebooks and evidently that tool expresses things in the odd way you've so well critiqued. My vague understanding of Calibre is that it is oriented toward making ebooks in a way that the the developers think is efficient and works on many popular readers.